# Убрать диалог прогресса по окончанию загрузки

Tags: java, android

Пытаюсь реализовать следующее: в `MainActivity` есть компоненты `TextView` и `Button`. При запуске приложение должно получить `title` с WEB-ресурса. (`title` идет в переменную `String name`). При нажатии на кнопку в `TextView` должен вывестись полученный `title`.

Покуда значение `name` равно `null` - выводится диалог прогресса. А как только значение `name` становится не равным `null`, диалог прогресса должен исчезнуть.

Я реализовал это, но после получения `title` диалог прогресса не исчезает.

Код моего приложения:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    TextView tv;
    Button bt;
    String name;
    ProgressDialog pd;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // найдем View-элементы
        tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);
        bt = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bt);

        //Парсим
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Document doc = null;
                try {
                    doc = Jsoup.connect("http://yandex.ru").get();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                name = doc.title();
                System.out.println("Название страницы: " + name);
            }
        }).start();

        //Диалог прогресса
        if (name == null) {
            pd = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "Ожидайте", "Выполняю соединение с ресурсом", true, false); //start
        }
        else {
            pd.dismiss(); //stop
        }

        //Слушаем кнопку
        OnClickListener oclBtnOk = new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                tv.setText("Название страницы: " + name);
            }
        };

        // присвоим обработчик кнопке
        bt.setOnClickListener(oclBtnOk);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для того, чтобы прогресдиалог появлялся в начале выполнения задачи и закрывался после ее выполнения он должен запускаться перед задачей, а отключаться в этой же задаче по ее окончанию:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
 TextView tv;
 Button bt;
 String name;
 ProgressDialog pd;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // найдем View-элементы
    tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);
    bt = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bt);

    pd = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "Ожидайте", "Выполняю соединение с ресурсом", true, false); //start

    //Парсим
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Document doc = null;
            try {
                doc = Jsoup.connect("http://yandex.ru").get();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            pd.dismiss(); //stop
            name = doc.title();
            System.out.println("Название страницы: " + name);
        }
    }).start();

    //Слушаем кнопку
    OnClickListener oclBtnOk = new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            tv.setText("Название страницы: " + name);
        }
    };

    // присвоим обработчик кнопке
    bt.setOnClickListener(oclBtnOk);
 }
}
```

В вашем случае происходит следующее. Метод onCreate() выполняется только один раз при старте активити. Во время его выполнения проверяемое условие - `null` и прогресс запускается. Повторно же этот код уже не выполняется, пока активити не будет пересоздана и больше условие проверятся не будет, поэтому ваш прогресс никогда не остановится.